# How to use setMouseCallback to draw random line?

Tags: c++, opencv

I've studied Opencv's setMouseCallback function.

I understand there are several events, list below:

CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE 0,
CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN 1, 
CV_EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN 2,
CV_EVENT_MBUTTONDOWN 3,
CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP 4, 
CV_EVENT_RBUTTONUP 5,
CV_EVENT_MBUTTONUP 6,
CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK 7,
CV_EVENT_RBUTTONDBLCLK 8,
CV_EVENT_MBUTTONDBLCLK 9,

CV_EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON 1,
CV_EVENT_FLAG_RBUTTON 2,
CV_EVENT_FLAG_MBUTTON 4,
CV_EVENT_FLAG_CTRLKEY 8,
CV_EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY 16,
CV_EVENT_FLAG_ALTKEY 32,

and with the coordinates I get from these events, I can draw, for example: straight line, circle, ellipse...etc.

But instead of straight line, I want to draw random line, just like the "pencil" or "brush" function in Microsoft Paint.

The CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE does return all the coordinates as my mouse move through the image, but I don't know how to combine it with CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN to represent "Start drawing line" and CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP to represent "Finish drawing line"?

Does anyone know how to achieve my requirement with setMouseCallback?

Comment: use buttondown event to start drawing (setting a bool to true), remember the last mouse position. then mousemove event (iff drawingBool is set true) to draw a line from last mouse position to current mouse position. stop drawing when mouseup event

Comment: Thanks for your advice, somehow gave me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself,

```
bool trigger;
Mat img;
void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int flag, int param)
{
    if(event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        img = Mat::zeros(320, 240, CV_8UC3);
        trigger = true;
    }
    if(event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP)
    {
        trigger = false;
    }
    if(event == CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE)
    {
        if(trigger == true)
        {
            line(img, cvPoint(x, y), cvPoint(x, y), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, CV_AA, 0);
            imshow("Drawing", img);
        }

    }

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    .
    .
    .
    cvsetMouseCallback("Origin img", onMouse, NULL);
    .
    .
    .
}
```